# "picture" should be a synonym for image

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I think the [picture](/questions/tagged/picture) tag should be a synonym for the [image](/questions/tagged/image) tag. I can't see any difference in the tag meaning. And "picture" has about 800 questions vs 35000+ for image.

Or should the picture tag simply removed? Not sure how this is handled.

Answer (score 6):

From the picture tag wiki:

> Considere using the image tag instead of the picture tag.

Pardoning the spelling mistake, we will take you up on your offer.

Also added [pictures](/questions/tagged/pictures) as a synonym.